# Are these two simple logic statements equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, boolean-algebra

I've got two statements:

1. Set X always contains 3.
2. Set X set never contains not 3.

My question: Are these two statements logically equivalent?

I ask this question because of an argument between my brother... Maybe language plays a role.

Comment: In set language you have "$X$ contains $3$", i.e. $3 \in X$ and "$X$ does **not** contain $3$", i.e. $3 \notin X$.

Comment: "Not $3$" makes no sense; we have to negate the "verb" (contain) and not the "object" (the number 3).

Comment: You could take not 3 as the complement of 3, so it never contains any number other than 3. This doesn't mean it contains 3 though.

Comment: In addition to the above, what do you mean by "always" and "never" here? Is $X$ something that varies with time?

Answer (score 1):

"Set $X$ always contains $3$," and "Set X never not contains 3" are equivalent.  It is the property of dual negation of the modal quantifier.
$$\Box\,(3\in X) ~\iff~ \neg \Diamond\, (3\notin X)$$

However, "Set X never contains not 3" is not the same thing at all.$$\neg\Diamond\,\exists x~(x\neq 3~\wedge~ x\in X)$$

The position of the "not" in a sentence is crucial to its meaning.

Consider $X=\{3, 4\}$.  This is plausible under each of the first two statements, but is implausible under the third.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent.
"Not 3" presumably means "any number other than 3".

The null set {} contains no "not 3" elements, but it doesn't contain 3 either. Therefore it is a counterexample to the claim that the two statements are equivalent.